# iOS how to iterate over collection and get user response for each item

Tags: ios, uialertview, blocking, uiactionsheet

This sort of thing has been asked a million times in a million different scenarios, but all of them revolve around obvious ways to break up the action and bypass the problem.  This may also be the case for me, but I am not seeing it.

I have a collection of Person objects that have multiple values for various attributes.  I need the user to chose which of those attributes to use for each object.  So, for example, I have aliases and addresses as attributes of the Person.  I need to enumerate the Persons, and ask the user which alias to use, then ask which address to use, then move on to the next Person.

I thought a UIActionSheet would handle that, but it does not block.

Currently, I am thinking I need to roll my own ActionSheet subclass, and stuff the Person object into it as a model, and then set the values in the actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: method, but am hoping there is some other way to do it.

Any input greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: You shouldn't need to block to do this. Use a controller object that manages the series of interactions needed for choosing the attributes.

Comment: Still the same issue, though, isn't it?  As I iterate over each Person, the user will need to make a selection, and I need to associate the result of that selection with an object that has been passed by.  Right?

Comment: oh, I see what you are saying. Yes you'd have to use a controller to manage the iteration and not use built in looping constructs in order to do it that way.

Comment: Then maybe my idea of plugging the Person object in as the model for an ActionSheet-type view (or even an AlertView) is not such a bad idea?  I don't care if they stack up one on top of the other... in fact that might be good, as the user will just click through them in rapid succession (there will only ever be a small handful of them).

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't need to subclass `UIActionSheet` for that, just have an object serve as action sheet's delegate and manage the flow through the delegate callbacks :)

Comment: And handle the iteration by hand instead of using a built-in loop construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudocode, here's what I'd try. `self.persons` is the array to loop over, `self.cursor` keeps track of where you are in that array.

```
- (void)actionSheet:didSelectButtonAtIndex:
{
    Person *p = self.persons[self.cursor]
    p.property = [self propertyForButtonIndex:]
    self.cursor++
    [self presentSheetForCursor]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the chat, Carl.  Always helpful to bounce ideas off of others, especially when working in a vacuum.  While this will certainly work, and certainly answers my question, I am going to end up going with the View/Model approach as I have cases where a model may need to have choices made against two different sets of data.  This will allow me to avoid looping twice to handle those cases, and I can just blindly set the value chosen on the model attached to the AlertView/ActionSheet.